# How to draw subimage with Ruby Gosu library?

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I'm trying to draw on the screen the subimage of an `Image` instance using [this subimage method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/Gosu/Image#subimage-instance_method). It seems to be pretty straight forward to do it but when I call the function it returns a `NilClass` instead of a new `Image`.

The main image is defined as:

```
@bg_img = Gosu::Image.new("res/space1.jpg") # dimensions 1080 x 1920
```

when I run `@bg_img.draw(0,0,0)` it draws the image normally, but when I I try to cast it into a new image:

```
test = @bg_img.subimage(0,0, 100, 100) # from (0,0), get rectangle of 100x100 dimension
```

The variable `test` is assigned with a null and therefore can't `.draw` it. Am I doing something wrong here? Or, is there another way to draw the subimage? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `.subimage()` if your image is 1024 x 1024 or smaller. I'm not sure if there's a work-around, but because this limit is inspired by memory constraints, you would probably be better off just splitting your image into multiple images of size 512 x 512 or 1024 x 1024.

From the gosu docs:

> Caveats:
>
> - subimage only works if the image lives on a single texture. If the image was too large and had to be split up into several OpenGL textures, subimage will return nil (same as #gl_tex_info).

From the source code:

```
//! Returns the maximum size of an texture that will be allocated
//! internally by Gosu.
//! Useful when extending Gosu using OpenGL.
const unsigned MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 1024;
```

Answer (score 0):

Good news, Image#subimage works regardless of image size in Gosu 0.12.0 and later.